# Location is updated even when greater gps accuracy is set (kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers)

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm developing a sort of a navigation application. When the app launches, I set the `CLLocationManager` to the greatest available accuracy `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers`. Based on that value, I expect to have a location update just after nearly 3 kilometers . However, I keep having a location update `didUpdateLocations` every one second. If I set the `distanceFilter` to 10 (meters) for example, the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method is not called every one second. Is not setting the `desiredAccuracy` property enough to "configure" the GPS frequency ?

```
- (void)initAndStartCoreLocation
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

//    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing the two properties. `desiredAccuracy` is the _accuracy_ of the coordinates of your location. And as per Apple docs: `distanceFilter` is `The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated.` so in your case you want to set `distanceFilter` to 3 km

Comment: @somtingwong: well, I though that `desiredAccuracy` transparently sets `distanceFilter` property.

Comment: @somtingwong: So, if I set the `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers` and `distanceFilter` to 10 meters, I will receive a location update nearly every 10 meters with a very bad accuracy ?

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's Programming Guide:

> And remember that specifying a value of
>   kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers doesn’t prevent the location
>   service from returning better data. Most of the time, Core Location
>   can return location data with an accuracy within a hundred meters or
>   so.

That means that **desiredAccuracy** property on *CLLocationManager* sets the minimal accuracy that your app will receive.

For your need you should use **distanceFilter** property or filter incoming events by time (for example every 30 sec) in **didUpdateLocations** method.